# Regex for remove a certain number of character after a match

Tags: regex, string, character

I'm looking for a simple regular expression for this,

This is the input:

```
This is a sample text www.testdomainname.com/picsinsideit/stunningpictureofkays1381737242g8k4n-280x428.jpg this is also sample text
```

Output:

```
This is a sample text www.testdomainname.com/picsinsideit/stunningpictureofkays1381737242g8k4n.jpg this is also sample text
```

I want to remove the text `-280x428`, i.e. remove 8 characters before exactly the text `.jpg`
The width and height will be different for each images. so I want to search for text `.jpg` after it matches remove the 8 characters before it.

I was searched for many questions in here but didn't find the solution for it, please help me.

Comment: Please mention the language/regex engine and include your attempts at the problem in your question.

Comment: I was just want to replace the contents, using notepad++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to define your pattern you want to match and that is not difficult. Lets do it step by step.

- It starts with a "-", thats the same in the regex.
- Then there is a series of digits with a "x" inbetween. Create a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[\dx]`, where `\d` is a digit and match this one or more times using the `+` [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

  Doing it this way makes it more flexible, when there are numbers with more or less than 3 digits, so it would also replace stuff like "-1600x1200" or "-64x48".

  If you want to be more strict about the pattern, then do something like `\d{2,4}x\d{2,4}` which would only match 2 to 4 digits followed by an "x" and then 2 to 4 digits.
- match ".jpg" with `\.jpg`. The `.` needs escaping since it is a [special character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) in regex.

This results in

```
-[\dx]+\.jpg
```

then replace it with ".jpg"

See [it on Regexr](http://regexr.com?36nmb)

Comment: I didn't think about more widths, and I tired this. It was the perfect solution, I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: +1 for clear step-by-step, this finally gives me a sense of how to build my own regex for my particular situation

Comment: Seriously, I wish I could give more upvotes! I've been messing with this stuff for an hour on all those special learn-and-try websites, none of them explain it as good as you do here. Within 10 minutes of reading your answer I've created my own regex that does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the language you use and following what you want to do, I would propose the following regex:

```
^(.*).{8}(\.jpg.*)$
```

And `$1$2`as replacement string.

This will simply remove 8 characters in front of every .jpg as you wanted to.

If you want to be more flexible with regards to the width/height numbers, you could also use:

```
^(.*)-[^-]+(\.jpg.*)$
```

Which will basically look for everything between the `-` (including) and `.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches the 8 characters immediately before the text ".jpg":

```
.{8}(?=\.jpg)
```

If you're not sure how many characters there are, this matches any number of characters from and including the last hyphen before ".jpg":

```
-[^-]*(?=\.jpg)
```

Use the application language of your choice to replace it with a blank to delete it.

The whacky looking expression `(?=...)` is a "look ahead", which matches the regex therein but does not consume or capture the input it matches.